# Initialize jQuery tabs in a directive that update on route change with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am attmpting to initialize a jquery plugin for tabs. The whole directive thing is new to me but I got the following to work. However when I click another list item it does not re-initialize the tab section. Is there a way to re-initialize this every time I click on a new item and the ui-router changes the route or content?

EDIT: Maybe some needed clarity:

the tabs are simply a jQuery plugin to make my life easier. However the tabs need initialization before they work. I normally do this with a jQuery script on the bottom of my HTML but that didn't work with the Angular setup I have. Each item I click opens a details section with tabs. As is the first time I click a item it instantiates successfully and the tabs appear. However if I click another item the tabs don't work. It only works for one item even though they both have the attribute for my directive "tabstuff". UI router is just how I am controlling switching data.

```
app.directive('tabstuff', function() {
    var linker = function(scope, element, attr){
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  });
    };
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker
  };
});
```

Also as I mentioned I am new to the directive idea. Please feel free to help me improve any part of my code.

Comment: Explain what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to have unique state for each tab?

Comment: Nope, the tabs are simply a jQuery plugin to make my life easier. However the tabs need initialization before they work. I normally do this with a jQuery script on the bottom of my HTML but that didn't work with the Angular setup I have. Each item I click opens a details section with tabs. As is the first time I click a item it instantiates successfully and the tabs appear. However if I click another item the tabs don't work. It only works for one item even though they both have the attribute for my directive "tabstuff". UI router is just how I am controlling switching data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much better to use native angular features to create tabs directive.

You can use [sytabs](http://sydev.github.io/sytabs/)

index.html

```
<script src="path/to/sy-tabs.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['sy.tabs']);
```

To use syTabs, insert something like this in your HTML:

```
<sy-tabs>
  <sy-pane title="Pane 1">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
  </sy-pane>
  <sy-pane title="Pane 2">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
  </sy-pane>
  ...
</sy-tabs>
```